# How to connect vault CLI to Vault Cluster installed on k8s?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have installed the vault cluster in k8s (AKS), now i try to connect to that cluster with vault CLI
the problem is i can't find any info or documentation .
i downloaded the vault.exe,
but where do I configure it to connect to the cluster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to export some `env` to use the vault CLI:

```sh
// Your vault server address
$ export VAULT_ADDR=https://127.0.0.1:8200

// vault token
$ export VAULT_TOKEN= "****"

// If your server is secured with TLS
$ export VAULT_CACERT=ca.crt 
$ export VAULT_CLIENT_CERT=tls.crt
$ export VAULT_CLIENT_KEY=tls.key
```

Now, you ready to use the vault CLI.

```sh
$ vault status
Key             Value
---             -----
Seal Type       shamir
Initialized     true
Sealed          false
... ... ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much , can you explain me please where the hell it is hidden in the documentation of this vault cr***p

Comment: also im getting in the kubctl port forwarding this error on each vault status
existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
E0124 14:02:58.080614   22680 portforward.go:372] error copying from remote stream to local connection: readfrom tcp4 127.0.0.1:8200->127.0.0.1:58582: write tcp4 127.0.0.1:8200->127.0.0.1:58582: wsasend: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  
 But i do get result from the cluster

Comment: Seems like a port-forward issue

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to connect to vault.

1. Assuming you deployed vault in the vault namespace you can start shell.

Using kubectl:

```
kubectl exec -n vault -it vault-0 -- /bin/sh
```

After which you can login using root token:

```
vault login $VAULT_ROOT_KEY
```

> Note: you get root token when you do init (assuming the you
> followed the [official guide](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-deploy#initializing-the-vault) to init and unseal vault):
>
> ```
> kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault operator init -key-shares=1 -key-threshold=1 -format=json > keys.json
>
> VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY=$(cat keys.json | jq -r ".unseal_keys_b64[]")
> echo $VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY
>
> VAULT_ROOT_KEY=$(cat keys.json | jq -r ".root_token")
> echo $VAULT_ROOT_KEY
> ```
>
> Note 2: The default root token account has a specific root role and is not allowed
> manipulating secrets unless you allow it explicitly.

2. Using UI.
   Depending on how you deploy vault there are multiple ways to enable it.

Using config.hcl file value:

```
ui = true
```

You can provide config file directly with CLI:

```
vault server -config vault-server.hcl
```

or in K8s case providing it as a ConfigMap and a StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vault-config
  namespace: default
data:
  extraconfig-from-values.hcl: |-
    disable_mlock = true
    ui = true
    
    listener "tcp" {
      tls_disable = 1
      address = "[::]:8200"
      cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
    }
    storage "file" {
      path = "/vault/data"
    }
```

and apply the configmap:

```
kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml
```

In the StatefulSet set manifest you use this configmap and mount it as volume and then copy to the proper place to start with it:

*part of the manifest*

```
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: vault-config
    - name: home
      emptyDir: {}
  containers:
    - name: vault          
      image: hashicorp/vault:1.8.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
      - "/bin/sh"
      - "-ec"
      args: 
      - |
        cp /vault/config/extraconfig-from-values.hcl /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${HOST_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOST_IP|${HOST_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${POD_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|POD_IP|${POD_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${HOSTNAME}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOSTNAME|${HOSTNAME?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${API_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|API_ADDR|${API_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${TRANSIT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|TRANSIT_ADDR|${TRANSIT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        [ -n "${RAFT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|RAFT_ADDR|${RAFT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
        /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh vault server -config=/tmp/storageconfig.hcl
```

Finally if you use [helm charts](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/main/values.yaml) for deployment you just need to set values to enable UI:

```
ui:
  # True if you want to create a Service entry for the Vault UI.
  #
  # serviceType can be used to control the type of service created. For
  # example, setting this to "LoadBalancer" will create an external load
  # balancer (for supported K8S installations) to access the UI.
  enabled: true
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  # The service should only contain selectors for active Vault pod
  activeVaultPodOnly: false
  serviceType: "NodePort"
  serviceNodePort: 31000
  externalPort: 8200
  targetPort: 8200
```

With this you expose you UI service on the IP of your node with Nodeport 31000 (e.g. http://192.168.10.100:31000). If you have load-balancer controller installed then you can use `serviceType: "LoadBalancer"`